# Terraform, Python external provider does not provide nested objects

Tags: python, terraform

I am trying to find a way to return a nested dictionary using python external data provider. I am using `terraform_external_data` python package for now, however open for suggestion.
This is my code.

`terraform.tf`

```
provider "external" {
  version = "~> 1.2"
}

data "external" "vip_config" {
  program = ["python", "${path.module}/f5-terraform-ext-data.py"]

}

output "output_all_result_data" {
  value = data.external.vip_config.result
}
```

`f5-terraform-ext-data.py`

```
@terraform_external_data
def f5_ext_data(tf_query):

    tf_query.update({"name": "pool1"})

    return tf_query


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f5_ext_data()
```

The above works and gives me something like:

```
output_all_result_data = {
  "name": "pool1"
}
```

However what I am looking at it is a way to get a more nested dictionary. Like below:

`{"pool":[{"name":"pool1"},{"name":"pool2"}]}`

When I return this Data it doesn't work. It errors out as:

`Error: failed to execute "python": Values must be strings.`

Any suggestion how to make it work? I can make it work in Python, but it doesn't work with the data provider. Terraform gives me errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question with the exact error(s) terraform returns you.

Comment: Return it as a json string and then call `jsondecode()` on the result?

Comment: can you please ellaborate on `jsondecode()`? I didnt quite get that...
However when I do `json.dumps(tf_query)` it errors out like this.
`Error: failed to execute "python": Data must be a dictionary.`